# "permission denied" on ~/.ddev/ssh-auth-compose.yaml and router-compose.yaml

Tags: ubuntu-20.04, ddev

I got a problem on running ddev on my ubuntu 20.04.
Installation of ddev ran without any problems (ddev version v1.15.0), but if i try starting a container it always runs into following error:

```
.PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/user/.ddev/ssh-auth-compose.yaml' 
Failed to start api-bundle: failed to start ddev-ssh-agent: Failed to run docker-compose [-f /home/user/.ddev/ssh-auth-compose.yaml -p ddev-ssh-agent up --build --force-recreate -d], err='exit status 1', stdout='', stderr='.PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/user/.ddev/ssh-auth-compose.yaml''
```

I've already tried to give the ddev and home directory and all other directories above a full access (chmod -R 777) the user of the .ddev directory in my project is the same as my home directory owner.

Running .ddev with the same project on a diffrent Ubuntu 19.04 runs like charme.

If i omit the ddev-ssh-agent the container is starting, but crashing when trying to write to router-compose.yaml.

- Current docker version is 19.03.11, build dd360c7
- Docker-Compose version 1.25.5,

both installed via snap.

I have no clue what to try next,
so hopefully you can help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This sounds like the issue reported in https://github.com/drud/ddev/issues/2347 - Could you follow up there? When you follow up please provide the output of `ls -lR ~/.ddev` and also `ls -lR $HOME/.ddev` - you can do that in a gist if you want. (gist.github.com). Also, I see in the output you've shown a failure to access "/home/user/.ddev/ssh-auth-compose.yaml" - Does that mean your username is "user"? Or did you edit it? If your username is sensitive, you can contact me a number of ways more private if you want. Go though the github issue.

Comment: Another thing to do is just to remove those directories to start over. `sudo rm -r $HOME/.ddev` - But I think you may have more than one home directory, or an odd value in $HOME.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not install docker-compose with snap (other apt). This should solve your issue: https://github.com/drud/ddev/issues/2347#issuecomment-652804548